# Grouping in search display controller

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-data, uisearchbar, uisearchdisplaycontroller

In my Core Data app, I have an entity Person with names as attribute. 
I used following predicate logic to search the names.
It displays names when we search with a word. 
well but I want two groups of searched names as

1. Word containing anywhere in the name
2. Name starts withe the word.

both groups I want. How?

```
NSString *searchfilter = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"*%@*",savedSearchTerm_];
NSPredicate *filter = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"word like[c] %@", searchfilter];
[fetchRequest setPredicate:filter];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example should work for #1.

word is anywhere anywhere in the name:

```
NSString *searchfilter = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"*%@*",savedSearchTerm_];
NSPredicate *filter = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"word like[c] %@", searchfilter];
[fetchRequest setPredicate:filter];
```

name starts with the word:

```
NSString *searchfilter = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@*",savedSearchTerm_];
NSPredicate *filter = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"word like[c] %@", searchfilter];
[fetchRequest setPredicate:filter];
```

Comment: Thakns michael. yes u are correct  for #2. i know this method for #2.
But i want to display both of these in my table view when user search with a word.

Answer (score 1):

i think you have 2 options here:

1) `- (id)initWithFetchRequest:(NSFetchRequest *)fetchRequest managedObjectContext:(NSManagedObjectContext *)context sectionNameKeyPath:(NSString *)sectionNameKeyPath cacheName:(NSString *)name` pass `sectionNameKeyPath:` by what you want to group

2) group after selecting `- (NSArray *)executeFetchRequest:(NSFetchRequest *)request error:(NSError **)error`

Comment: Can u explain me how can i grouped in tableview.By using this code.
i want to display both of these searched groups in my table view when user search with a word